# Composite primary key in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I want to set a composite primary key in mongodb along with default primary key _id. How can we do it using mongoengine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.createIndex({_id: 1, otherVal: 1}, {unique: true});
```

if you want that `_id` will be a compund index by itself you need to define _id as an `Object`:

```
_id : {val : ObjectId("..."), other: ...}
```

[image: working proof]

> Unique Compound Index
>     You can also enforce a unique constraint on compound indexes, as in the   following prototype:
>   db.collection.createIndex( { a: 1, b: 1 }, { unique: true } )
>   These indexes enforce uniqueness for the combination of index keys and not for either key individually.

Comment: This is making both the values unique. I want the combination of two values as unique. Suppose if I've _id and version as primary keys, version can be same for different ids. The combination should be unique